# Unusual behavior of ADAM optimizer with AMSGrad

Tags: optimization, neural-network

I am trying some 1, 2, and 3 layer LSTM networks to classify land cover of some selected pixels from a Landsat time-series spectral data. I tried different optimizers (as implemented in Keras) to see which of them is better, and generally found AMSGrad variant of ADAM doing a relatively better job in my case. However, one strange thing to me is that for the AMSGrad variant, the training and test accuracies start at a relatively high value from the first epoch (instead of increasing gradually) and it changes only slightly after that, as you see in the below graph.

[Performance of ADAM optimizer with AMSGrad on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1pV3.png)

[Performance of ADAM optimizer with AMSGrad off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kudpH.png)

I have not seen this behavior in any other optimizer. Does it show a problem in my experiment? What can be the explanation for this phenomenon?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the number of LSTM layers. They are notorious for easily overfitting the data. Try a smaller model initially(less number of layers), and gradually increase the number of units in a layer. If you notice poor results, then try adding another LSTM layer, **but only after the previous step has been done.**

As for the optimizers, I have to admit I have never used AMSGrad. However, the plot with regard to the accuracy does seem to be much better in case of the AMSGrad off. You can see that when you use AMSGrad the accuracy on the training set is much better than that on the test set, which a strong sign of overfitting.

Remember to keep things simple, experiment with simple models and generic optimizers.

Comment: Many thanks for reply. I saw the above mentioned behavior in all 1, 2, or 3 layer configurations. My question was actually about the very high level of accuracy from the first epoch with AMSGrad on. Is there any explanation?

Comment: As for comparison with AMSGrad on and off, the above graphs may suggest some overfitting but actually it was not the case in many other of my simulations. For example I get a train/test accuracy of .713/.709 with AMSGrad off, but .745/.739 with AMSGrad on, or .852/.835 with AMSGrad off, but .885/.849 with AMSGrad on. I think these differences between train/test accuracy is typical and not a sign of overfitting, isn't it?.